# Запрос из Excel в Google таблицу, возврат массива

Tags: excel, vba, google-spreadsheet

Имеется *Google*-таблица, а на компьютере форма в *Excel*.

Как можно получить массив данных определенной строки из *Google*-таблицы посредством *Excel*? На компьютере вводится число, производится его поиск в определенной колонке,  при нахождении - возврат массива данных этой строки. В дальнейшем эти данные обрабатываются в *Excel*.

Я пытался реализовать посредством *Google*-скрипта, через *Get*-запросы, не вышло.

Comment: Выгрузить таблицу в *Excel* - не вариант?

Comment: Таблица постоянно обновляется.  Да наверно придется так делать раз в день скачивать таблицу ( или написать скрипт скачивания таблицы